# I can not start .bat file on the remote server

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, system, rdp

I can not start .bat file on the remote server, which should start services if they are disabled. The file runs only on the local computer.

```
@echo off

sc query "$Servicename$" | find /i "RUNNING"
if not ERRORLEVEL 1 (echo Service zapushen) else (net start $Servicename$)

pause
```

I can start it on my local computer, but can't start it on remote desktop panel

How can I fix it?

Comment: have you tried manually start servcie remotely?

Comment: i know what you mean, but let's start diagnosis

Comment: I mean when I write a script on the rdp server itself and try to run it, it does not work, but it works on the local computer . Yes, it works when I try to run the script manually by connecting to the rdp

Comment: where is `$Servicename$` assgined? is it env variable? and is this windows bat? you may want try powershell.

Comment: I made this script for the powershell too, yes it works according to the rdp, but here another problem comes out, this is that it (the powershell script) does not want to run through the task scheduler, because this script will have to be executed every 5 minutes )))